# Prove the probability to even number of "Heads" is $\frac{1}{2}$.

Tags: probability

> Let $n$ coins, where **at least** one of them is a fair coin. Each one of the $n$ coins is tossed - Prove the probability to get even number of "Heads" is $\frac{1}{2}$.

I'd be glad for a direction.

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Lat $A$ be one of the fair coins. Let $p$ be the probability that the number of "heads" among the rest (i.e., the coins $\ne A$) is even. Then the probability for a total number of even "heads" is $$P(A\text{ tails})P(\text{rest even})+P(A\text{ heads})P(\text{rest odd})=\frac12p+\frac12(1-p)=\frac12.$$

Comment: Can you explain $\frac12p+\frac12(1-p)$?

Comment: @AlonAlon: This is Bayes's formula, conditioning on whether $A$ turned up heads (the second term) or tails (the first term).

Answer (score 0):

Toss a coin a million times. Tally the number of heads you obtain. Divide by the number of toss. The result should be close to 1/2, proving that the probability of heads is 1/2.

Comment: This is not answering the question. You're tossing a fair coin here!

Comment: Also the question specifically says "prove".